# Adding a new Map to a existing Nested Map throws error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, data-structures

I got two maps InputSpec and Map("db" -> "targetDB").
InputSpec is nested Map converted from a json like below

```
Map(id -> Map(prepped -> prepInput), params -> Map(extraParams -> Map(exMap -> Map(obj -> scores, science -> SScoresOD, handler -> hiveHandler), features -> List(a, b, c, d, e, r1, r2, r4, s), category -> AD, exclude -> true, subName -> CD, cxMap -> Map(obj -> scores, science -> SScoresOD, handler -> hiveHandler), Name -> af), Partition -> 10000000))
```

I want to extract exMap and cxMap and add one more key , value to it i.e "db" -> "targetDB" along side rest of the `obj -> scores, science -> SScoresOD, handler -> hiveHandler ,db -> targetDB`
So that the final Map would be ::

```
Map(id -> Map(prepped -> prepInput), params -> Map(extraParams -> Map(exMap -> Map(obj -> scores, science -> SScoresOD, handler -> hiveHandler , db -> targetDB), features -> List(a, b, c, d, e, r1, r2, r4, s), category -> AD, exclude -> true, subName -> CD, cxMap -> Map(obj -> scores, science -> SScoresOD, handler -> hiveHandler, db -> targetDB), Name -> af), Partition -> 10000000))
```

The solution I tried was below ::

```
    final def mergeMapsLeftBiased[A <: Any](mapL: Map[A, Any], mapR: Map[A, Any]): Map[A, Any] = {
            println("mergeMapsLeftBiased")
            val localSeq = mapR toList
        
            val resultMap = if (mapL contains localSeq.head._1) mapL else mapL ++ Map(localSeq.head)
            if (localSeq.tail isEmpty) resultMap else mergeMapsLeftBiased(resultMap, localSeq.tail.toMap)                                                        
        }
        
val f = mergeMapsLeftBiased(inputDataSpecs,Map("db"-> "targetDB"))
```

But it append the Map("db"->"targetDB") at the end and gives below output ::

```
Map[String,Any] = Map(id -> Map(prepped -> prepInput), params -> Map(extraParams -> Map(exMap -> Map(obj -> scores, science -> SScoresOD, handler -> hiveHandler), features -> List(a, b, c, d, e, r1, r2, r4, s), category -> AD, exclude -> true, subName -> CD, cxMap -> Map(obj -> scores, science -> SScoresOD, handler -> hiveHandler), Name -> af), Partition -> 10000000), db -> targetDB)
```

I don't know how that can be achieved .
Let me know your solutions

Comment: `.get` on a `Map` gives you an `Option`

Comment: That ^^. And there is also no value with that key in your map (that's why you got `None`).

Comment: But exMap has another Map with 3 fields , right ? exMap -> Map(obj -> scores, science -> SScoresOD, handler -> hiveHandler

Comment: @AbhishekPriyankar I don't know. In your example `inputSpecs` is an array. And the map it contains, has `exMap` at third level (`params -> extraParams -> exMap`) 
Check out this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Dima - I took your advice and edited the question for better understanding. Thanks . Yes, to change exMap at 3rd level is what I want to achieve

Comment: @AbhishekPriyankar still same two problems: (1) `Map.get` returns an `Option`, and you are trying to cast it to `Map`, and (2) there is _no_ `"exMap"` key in your `inputSpecs`.

Comment: @Dima If you can see the 2nd solution , 1st one is wrong , I was able to add the Map , but it got added in the end . exMap is present in inputDataSpecs or inputSpec (sorry for confusion)

Comment: Remove the "wrong solution", keep just the one you need help with, and explain what exactly is the problem (I have no idea what "added to the end" means, and what you want to happen instead).
Also show the actual map, that contains that key. The one you have in the question does not.

Comment: Looks like you are just confused with all the nested maps ... Just try writing out what you are trying to do step-by-step accurately: (1) get `params` from original map (2) get `extraParams` from that (3) get `exMap` from that (4) add new entry to the last result (4) put result into `exMap` in (3), (5) put result of (4) into `extraParams` in (2), (6) put result of (5) into `params` in (1). There is nothing difficult about it, it's just your data structure is shitty and very confusing. My advice would be get rid of maps in the first place, and replace them with case classes.